# PWM in Linux driver insmod

Tags: timer, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to insmod a pwm triple timer counter(TTC) driver for Zynq PS. The dmesg log is:

```
TTC: Inside probe function
pwm-cadence f8001000.timer: PWM 0 has clock source 0 at 108333336 Hz
pwm-cadence f8001000.timer: PWM 1 has clock source 0 at 108333336 Hz
pwm-cadence f8001000.timer: PWM 2 has clock source 0 at 108333336 Hz
pwm-cadence f8001000.timer: cannot add pwm chip (error -22)
```

Does the EINVAL (error -22) function occur when certain fields in struct cpwm->chip are uninitialised? 
I am a newbie in this field. So any tips would be appreciated.

```
static int cadence_pwm_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct cadence_pwm_chip *cpwm;
    struct resource *r_mem;
    int ret;
    struct device_node *node = pdev->dev.of_node;
    const __be32 *value;
    int rlen;
    char propname[24];
    int i;
    struct cadence_pwm_pwm *pwm;
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "TTC: Inside probe function\n");
    cpwm = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev, sizeof(*cpwm), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!cpwm)
        return -ENOMEM;

    r_mem = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
    cpwm->base = devm_ioremap_resource(&pdev->dev, r_mem);
    if (IS_ERR(cpwm->base))
       return PTR_ERR(cpwm->base);

    for (i = 0; i < CPWM_NUM_PWM; i ++) {
       pwm = cpwm->pwms + i;

    snprintf(propname, sizeof(propname), "xlnx,ttc-clk%d-freq-hz", i);

    value = of_get_property(node, propname, &rlen);
    if (value)
       pwm->clk_hz = be32_to_cpup(value);
    else {
       dev_err(&pdev->dev, "missing %s property1", propname);
       return -ENODEV;
    }

    snprintf(propname, sizeof(propname), "xlnx,ttc-clk%d-clksrc", i);

    value = of_get_property(node, propname, &rlen);
    if (value)
       pwm->source = be32_to_cpup(value);
    else {
       dev_err(&pdev->dev, "missing %s property2", propname);
       return -ENODEV;
    }

    dev_info(&pdev->dev, "PWM %d has clock source %d at %d Hz", i, pwm->source, pwm->clk_hz);

}

cpwm->chip.dev = &pdev->dev;
cpwm->chip.ops = &cadence_pwm_ops;
cpwm->chip.npwm = CPWM_NUM_PWM;
cpwm->chip.base = -1;

ret = pwmchip_add(&cpwm->chip);
if (ret < 0) {
    dev_err(&pdev->dev, "cannot add pwm chip (error %d)", ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Link for the whole driver:https://github.com/XiphosSystemsCorp/cadence-ttc-pwm/blob/master/src/kernel/pwm-cadence.c

Comment: Usually one adds *initcall_debug* to the kernel command line to see more details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code looks decent. This means that adding PWM chip must not fail - all fields required are set and they are fine.

However, `EINVAL` could still be returned as per the only remaining reason, namely, because support for PWM (`CONFIG_PWM`) has been disabled in the kernel build config. This follows from `include/linux/pwm.h` file where conditional compilation is used. So, if `CONFIG_PWM` option has been enabled, then a proper symbol exists. And, when you build your driver, [this](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pwm.h#L434) function prototype will be used from the header. But if the kernel has been built without PWM support, then [inline function](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pwm.h#L510) will be used during driver compilation, which is a simple stub to return `EINVAL` in any case.

All in all, you need to check your build configuration properly.

Comment: Thanks insmod was successful. Just out of curiosity, plugged the PWM output into a CRO. The PWM signal seemed to be modulated upon a sine wave. Is this normal?